# Python3 subprocess check_output returns empty for some commands

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am a python3 beginner. I am trying to get the java version with a python3 script. After I checked the docs, I saw that subprocess.check_output might be what I need.

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["java", "-version"])
print("Output is {}".format(output))
```

The problem is the output I am getting is

```
Output is b''
```

Why am I not getting the correct string that I get with bash?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some reason your output lands in the `stderr`. You can pipe that to the return value like this:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["java", "-version"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

If somebody knows why it goes to `stderr`, I'd be happy to hear it. `["python", "--version"]`, for example, works as expected.

Comment: I can confirm: `java -version` command prints to stderr on my system. `man java` doesn't specify where the output should go. Your code covers both stdout/stderr therefore unless `java -version` [prints directly to terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20981435/4279); it should work.