# Can't retrieve output from subprocess check_output

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm wondering how to save the output of the program in a file.

In particular, I'm trying to save all output from vowpal_wabbit application to a file, when running it from the Python like that:

```
rez1 = subprocess.check_output([parameters], shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
print(rez1)
```

However it printed out nothing, while the program itself executes well. It's strange because when run from the Terminal with the very same parameters it provides me some useful information.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

P.S. Python 3.4.1 (IPython via Anaconda), Mac OS X

Comment: How many lines printed from the process?

Comment: don't use a list argument with `shell=True` it is an error in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some programs write to stdout and also stderr. To build on @Tichodroma's code, the following prints 'stdout' to stdout, 'stderr' to stderr, merges the two streams, and captures both outputs correctly:

### source

```
import subprocess

res = subprocess.check_output(
    "echo stdout; /bin/echo stderr 1>&2",
    shell=True,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    )
print 'DATA:', res.replace('\n', '.')
print 'END'
```

### output

```
DATA: stdout.stderr.
END
```

Comment: Works just fine. Thank a lot! By the way, it appears `subprocess.Popen(...)` also could handle this. What method is better?

Comment: I like the `check_xx` functions because they raise exceptions if the program exits with an error.  They're obvious, and I like obvious :)

Comment: @user3058525: A program may also [print to a terminal directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20981435/4279). You might need `screen` utility to capture such output.

Comment: nitpick: use `universal_newlines=True` on Python 3 to enable the text mode. And `print s` -> `print(s)`.

Answer (score 2):

If your program prints to `STDOUT`, you are using [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) correctly. A working example:

```
res = subprocess.check_output("date", shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
Thu Jul 10 09:49:31 CEST 2014\n
```