# Subprocess Deadlock

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, subprocess

I have a shell script which I need to invoke in the Python program.

```
from subprocess import *
p=Popen('some_script',stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate('S')
```

But after the communicate() command is executed the process goes for a deadlock. The shell script has not been written by me and I cannot modify it. I just need to kill the process after the communicate() method is executed, but the program should not exit.
Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Thanks, @Joachim for helping me out with the formatting!

Comment: are you sure that `some_script` reads its input from stdin and not from the terminal/console directly?

Comment: Yes, 'some_script' reads input from terminal/console but I want to supply input from the program

Comment: Are you sure? For example, it implies that you can provide input manually despite `stdin=PIPE`.

Comment: Yes, I can run 'some_script' manually in console/terminal and provide whatever input is required. All I want is to invoke it through a program automatically, so as the manual operation can be omitted.

Comment: no. It is not what I said. Can you provide the input (type S on the keyboard) manually if you run the code from your question that contains `stdin=PIPE`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Can you reiterate your point? By default, stdin *is* the initial console, inherited from the python process. The entire point of `stdin=Pipe`  is to give it a new pipe controlled by python. Unless one does some serious digging inside `/proc`, the subprocess cannot reconnect to the initial stdin.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the code can read from terminal directly bypassing stdin. Here's [code example that prints to console directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20981435/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Seriously? Just assume that I placed ", etc" after mentioning `/proc`...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi what is your point? Reading from a tty directly is not exotic (it is common for applications that accept a user  password, see [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)). `some_script` expecting an input from a tty may be one of the possible explanations of the observed behavior described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The entire point of Popen.communicate is that it will wait until the process terminates. If this is not desired behavior, you must explicitly interact with the process' [stdin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout)/stdout/stderr.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('some_script', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('S\n')
p.kill()
```

Comment: Still the process is not being killed

Comment: @Saurabh `Popen.kill()` will send `SIGKILL` to the process. If the process survives this, the script you are calling is seriously flawed. Can you provide more information on what it's supposed to do? Is any I/O involved that may possibly block?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it is not surprising that `.kill()` may leave running processes behind. [SIGKILL always works](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5642/1321) but it doesn't kill the whole process tree e.g., see [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The shell script submits NASTRAN jobs in the cluster queue for running. For submitting the job I just have to hit 'S'.But from the python program, after 'S' is entered the shell script goes in a deadlock and any subsequent commands are left unexecuted.