# python execute exe file with script, enter username, password, etc

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess, popen

I want to call an exe-file and already input parameters/input-data.

```
cmd = dir_path + 'file.exe do something test'
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

This is already working fine. If you do that by using the exe-file you would press enter to execute the next step which would be entering your username. Then password and so on. Now I dont know how to implement this into my script, that this steps are all done my the script. Basically i dont know how to do the ENTER step with python. Thx for any help.

**UPDATE**

Tried now 2 ways (all mentioned within this question or others on stackoverflow).

*way 1>*

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
# cmd represents the path of the exe file 
p.stdin.write(username+"\n")
p.stdin.write(password+"\n")
p.sdin.close()
```

*way 2*

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

out,err = p.communicate("\n".join([username,password,"\n"]))
# last \n should terminate the exe file and communicate should wait for the process to exit
```

Both ways present me with the same output in one line:

> Username: Password:

normally i hoped it would be:

> Username: "username wrote by process + \n" 
>   Password: "password wrote by process + \n"

the application is running on windows7 (has to be) and the exe file runs within command line.

So is it maybe possible that the exe does not support *way1* and *way2* so its not possible to write it through a subprocesss or am I making a major mistake?!

thanks again for any help.

Comment: search for `PyAutoIt`

Comment: looks good, but i cannot install software or libs on my working pc. is there a solution with subprocess or something similar ?

Comment: How do you normally entering username, password? Is it a GUI application? Note: [the application may read/write directly to the console outside of its standard input/output streams](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20980965/4279) i.e., `stdin=PIPE` might not help. What is your OS? On Unix, you could [use `pexpect` and here's why](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there!

You can do the following:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
p.communicate(input='\r')
```

You may need to use \n instead of \r if there are any problems. \r is a carriage return, and \n is a newline.

Comment: hmm ok. means that communicate sends an "\r" which terminates. but i want to stay in "terminal" and just make a "virtual" enter.

Comment: /r should simulate a carriage return (which is an enter press), but /n would be a newline. Does /n work for you?

Comment: ah ok. so if want to add a new cmd after the '\r' can i do another p.communicate(input='some cmd') or do i need to Popen another subprocess (guess not wouldnt make sense).

Comment: means: 1. cmd = "file.exe parameter" 2. input="\r" 3. new cmd = username 4. input = "\r" and so on

Comment: @vicR If `cmd` accepts input from its stdin then you could pass the input as: `p.communicate("\n".join([username, password, etc])` (pass `universal_newlines=True` to `Popen()`, to enable text mode). To emulate Enter, pass `'\n'`.

Comment: @RobBlagg, I would encourage you to file a new request for that question, since it seems a bit different.